# Where to set default values to properties in Gradle?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, properties, gradle, task

I have Custom Task:

```
public class GenerateTask extends SourceTask {
    @Input @Optional
    String inputEncoding = "UTF-8"

    @Input @Optional
    String outputEncoding  = "UTF-8"
...
}
```

So I want to make this properties Optional, but I need they to have some value, so I want to assign them 'UTF-8', so where is the best place to do that? In inicialisation(like I did it) or in the task constructor or somewhere else?

Comment: Like You did it. This is definitely good place.